# How To: Assigning a value to a sub property of an indexed default property via "setter"

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.2-tokyo

I have a class which contains the profile information of a project of mine, with loads and loads of information, its called PROFILE. To have an easy access to all the different properties of this profile I have an indexed default property. This default property(TCHANNELLIST) is a record containig again a few properties as well as another record(TCHANNELPARAMETER). The property CHANNEL is the default property (indexed) of the default property TCHANNELLIST.

Now I do have a problem when constructing the setter of these properties. (To clearify: the read function is not the problem! Please don't bother except the solution can be found in it).

The Question: How do I construct the Property/procedure/function to get the following code running

```
MyProfile[i][j].Name := 'Thanks_for_the_help';
```

Since more is more here is the structure of my records I have used. I am also willing to change the general structure if there is a better way, so I am open for suggestions.

```
TChannelParameter = record                                                        
  // each channel gets one record for itself
  public
    channelType                     : TKanalTyp;
    display_number                  : Integer;    
    Name                            : string;
    // and a few other but you will get the idea...
  end;

TChannelList = record
  private
    FChannelparameter_List           : array of TChannelParameter ; 
    function GetChannelParameter(Index: Integer): TChannelParameter ;
    procedure SetChannelParameter(Index: Integer); //Here I need some help
  public
    property Channal_GlobalNumber[index: Integer]: TChannelParameter read GetChannelParameter write SetChannelParameter; //Here I need some help
  end;
```

To be honest I just don't have an idea (and I cant find any help online) to get that line of code running. To Read everything is not a problem but to write stuff into the "subitem" of an indexed default property is a riddle to me. Here it does not matter if I use this

```
A_Channel_list[i].name := 'aName';
```

or

```
MyProfile[i][j].name := 'aName';
```

Both setters are till now not constructed! Since I lack the basic knowledge to do so! (further I did not  include the class since the handling should be the same)

If I get one running the other one should not be a problem anymore. Maybe somebody knows that this kind of operation however is not possible, please also let me know this! I will then reconstruct my class and records.

Comment: Change record to class 
Because records are value types this will never work.

Comment: To explain that a bit more: When you write MyProfile[i] you get a copy of that TChannelList record. Everything following is done on that copy, so it doesn't find its way into the original data structure.

Comment: Ok! I will take those notes and go with classes then! Thank you very much! The nested records seem to work (in a first trial to read the stuff beneath) but I will double check!

Comment: Ok, so I tried changing the records to classes, but the overall conecept is still unclear. Since I would like to have a few operations in-between the levels I need to use properties. But I can't find a solution to tell the subtitem,for example, ChannelParameter.name to change, because I can't get the setter function, setchannelparamter, right. Any concrete ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what you are trying to achieve you don't even need `Channal_GlobalNumber` property to be writable. Having it readable would be enough provided that your `TChannelParameter` object is class type instead record type that you have now.

You see if you declare your `TChannelParameter` as class your `Channal_GlobalNumber` property will return you a reference (pointer) to that object so you can then access any of its fields/properties like if you would have variable referencing such object.

This means that you could then be changing name property/field of individual channels simply by using:

```
A_Channel_list[i].name := 'aName';
```

So why doesn't this work when your `TChannelParameter` is of record type. As **Uwe Raabe** wrote in his comment your indexed property of record type won't return you the original record from your array but instead a copy of it. Therefore making any hanges on it would not change the original record from your array but instead copy.

**EDIT:** Don't forget that if you change your `TChannelParameter` object to class type you will have to write special routines for creating such object when you are changing size of your `FChannelparameter_List` array as in such case this array is array of poiters to `TChannelParameter` classes.

Now if you want to realy avoid this and use records only you could write multiple indexed properties in `TChannelList` object one for each field of `TChannelParameter` record. So then you can use these properties getter or setter method to Access items in your array.

Unfortunately I can't write you a code example righht now since I'm not on my development computer.

Comment: hm.... honestly I tried that... maybe I have still a problem somewhere else. I double check my constructors and stuff maybe I forgot something... Thanks for the reply! Appreciate it

Comment: thanks SilverWarrior.... I got it up and running finally.... I (probably) forgot to change one record when I tried it the first time... Now the problem is solved! I only need to write the right routins but this is just fine  :) thaks a lot!

Comment: I'm guessing that in your first atempt you probably just changed your `TChannelList ` into class while in fact it can remain to record type but you do need to change `TChannelParameter` so that your indexed property is returning reference to your object and not its copy.

Comment: Ok. So I got it. The original is a little bit more complex of course. In the first trial I forgot to change another related record to a class, since I thought this would not affect anything (know after debuging everything I know better) After your answer I simply changed all records to classes and ... it worked :) Know I néed to differ this again a little, but this will work out I am sure of it :) thanks a lot for the help I was somehow at a loss with this